# zsh: command not found: bundle (after gem install bundle)

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, openbsd

Why `zsh: command not found: bundle` after `gem install bundler`?

I tried setting `path=( /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2/gems/ ~/bin /bin /sbin /usr/bin /usr/sbin /usr/local/bin /usr/local/sbin )` in `/etc/zshrc` and `source /etc/zshrc` to no avail.

```
root@dev:/home/dev# gem install bundler
Successfully installed bundler-1.7.12
Parsing documentation for bundler-1.7.12
Done installing documentation for bundler after 10 seconds
1 gem installed

root@dev:/home/dev# bundle
zsh: command not found: bundle

root@dev:/home/dev# uname -a
OpenBSD dev.my.domain 5.7 GENERIC#748 amd64

root@dev:/home/dev# gem environment
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 2.4.5
  - RUBY VERSION: 2.2.0 (2014-12-25 patchlevel 0) [x86_64-openbsd]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /usr/local/bin/ruby22
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin
  - SPEC CACHE DIRECTORY: /root/.gem/specs
  - SYSTEM CONFIGURATION DIRECTORY: /etc
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-openbsd
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2/gems/
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
     - :update_sources => true
     - :verbose => true
     - :backtrace => false
     - :bulk_threshold => 1000
  - REMOTE SOURCES:
     - https://rubygems.org/
  - SHELL PATH:
     - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2/gems/
     - /root/bin
     - /bin
     - /sbin
     - /usr/bin
     - /usr/sbin
     - /usr/local/bin
     - /usr/local/sbin
```

Comment: If someone googling gets this error: I solved it just closing and opening the tab again. It was an issue related with deploying on Heroku.

Comment: .zshrc -- export PATH=$HOME/bin:/usr/local/bin:$PATH

Answer (score 36):

I had the same issue using zsh and this fixed it:

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshenv
$ echo 'source $HOME/.zshenv' >> ~/.zshrc
$ exec $SHELL
```

Comment: Did not work for me inside a `conda` environment: `/home/gabriel/.zshenv:2: command not found: rbenv` as explained here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58896403/zshenv2-command-not-found-rbenv

Answer (score 28):

You seem to be after installing `bundler` system-wide. To do this, you need to pass `--no-user-install` flag to `gem` and execute it with `sudo`:

```
sudo gem install bundler --no-user-install
```

After this, you should see `bundle` in `/usr/bin/` just fine:

```
$ ls /usr/bin/bundle
/usr/bin/bundle*
```

Comment: I thought you should avoid using sudo on gems, but maybe with --no-user-install flag its for multi user installation

Answer (score 11):

You can check the directory in which Rubygems will install gem executables with `gem environment`.

One of the first points should be `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY`. Make sure this directory is in your `$PATH` (listed as `SHELL PATH` btw)

Comment: This is weird... have you verified the binary actually IS PRESENT in the directory?

Comment: Indeed, running `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.2/gems/bundler-1.7.12/bin/bundle` seems to work.

Comment: The Binary should also be present in `EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /usr/local/bin` - is it?

Comment: Ooh - it's there as `bundle22` :)

Comment: Do I have to manually symlink all of the binaries or is there a better way?

Comment: Hm usually rubygems should create it correctly (as `bundle` and not `bundle22`)... But to be honest I have no idea what could have caused this :)

Answer (score 7):

You shound run the below command after installed `bundler`:

```
rbenv rehash
```

Answer (score 2):

Also just ran into the same error when setting up jekyll. My `gem env` shows `GEM PATHS` as follows:

```
- GEM PATHS:
    - /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0
```

The content of this directory looks like this:

```
bin/            cache/          extensions/     specifications/
build_info/     doc/            gems/
```

Inside `bin`, I see both `jekyll` and `bundle`:

```
$cd /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/
$ls
bundle        jekyll        listen        safe_yaml     sass-convert
bundler       kramdown      rougify       sass          scss
```

---

If you find similar paths and files as I do, any one of the following approaches should work:

- Append the full path `/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/` to `PATH` via:

  ```
  export PATH="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/:$PATH"
  ```
- Make symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin` via:

  ```
  $cd /usr/local/bin
  $ln -sf /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/bundle .
  $ln -sf /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/jekyll .
  ```
- Set up aliases in `.zshrc` (or `.bashrc` and alike):

  ```
  alias jekyll="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/jekyll"
  alias bundle="/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/bin/bundle"
  ```

---

In general, I felt all this path blindness makes the experience of setting up a jekyll site bumpier than expected:( If others have a set of steps that just work (without such needs for troubleshooting), please comment :)