# .zshenv:2: command not found: rbenv

Tags: ruby, zsh, rbenv, zshrc

When switching from bash to zsh, I looked up how to resolve an issue with my rbenv folder not being used correctly by zsh and [found this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34362519/1391441):

```
$ echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
$ echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.zshenv
$ echo 'source $HOME/.zshenv' >> ~/.zshrc
$ exec $SHELL
```

I ran all of these and seem to be using the correct rbenv folder now, but I get this error message whenever I open a new iTerm window:

```
/Users/myname/.zshenv:2: command not found: rbenv
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Try removing rbenv and reinstalling from scratch.

Comment: You shouldn't need the last line; `.zshenv` is sourced automatically before `.zshrc` is.

Comment: Are you sure `rbenv` is, in fact, in `$HOME/.rbenv/bin`?

Comment: @ahrampy did any of the comments or my answer help you? Can you please give us feedback or accept the answer?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to add two things to your `PATH`.
First `rbenv` itself and second the ruby `shims`.

## Part 1 rbenv

### Installation

#### Homebrew

If you installed `rbenv` with `brew`,
then the `rbenv` executable should be linked to `/usr/local/bin/rbenv`.

See [homebrew installation documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos) for details.

Please add `/usr/local/bin` to your path `PATH`, if it is missing.

```
# in ~/.zshrc

export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH
```

#### Github Checkout

If you install `rbenv` via a Github checkout, then the `rbenv` executalbe should be stored in `~/.rbenv/bin`.

See [github installation documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#basic-github-checkout) for details.

Please add `~/.rbenv/bin` to your path `PATH`, if it is missing.

```
# in ~/.zshrc

export PATH=$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH
```

### Verfiy

Please verify that `rbenv` is in your path by calling `which rbenv`.
The installation path should be returend.

## Part 2 shims

Add the ruby `shims` to you path.

```
# in ~/.zshrc

eval "$(rbenv init -)"
```

Instead of the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` command you can also add the `shims` folder directly.

```
# in ~/.zshrc

export RBENV_ROOT=$HOME/.rbenv
export PATH=$RBENV_ROOT/shims:/versions:$PATH
```

## Part 3 rbenv doctor

You might also run the `rbenv-doctor` script mentioned [here](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#homebrew-on-macos),
to check your installation.

Comment: Funnily enough, I skipped straight to the brew doctor script `curl -fsSL https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv-installer/raw/master/bin/rbenv-doctor | bash` and it identified the one thing I had missed, saving a lot of time

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem...
when I ran ruby or rbenv, I got this error "command not found"

try this:

```
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv

echo 'eval "$(rbenv init - zsh)"' >> ~/.zshenv

echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.zshenv
```

Answer (score 3):

I had this same error. I could run `which rbenv` and `rbenv` just fine, but no matter what I would get `command not found: rbenv`. The issue was that I had `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in my `~/.zshenv` and not my `~/.zshrc` file. You may still have the path to `rbenv` be added to `$PATH` within `~/.zshenv` for it to work.